# pandas Add and rename multiple columns based on single column using concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
  group owner  failed granted_pe  slots
0    g1    u1       0     single      1
1   g50   u92       0     shared      8
2   g50   u92       0     shared      1
```

`df` can be created using this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['g1', 'u1', 0, 'single', 1],
                   ['g50', 'u92', '0', 'shared', '8'],
                   ['g50', 'u92', '0', 'shared', '1']], 
                  columns=['group', 'owner', 'failed','granted_pe', 'slots'])
df = (df.astype(dtype={'group':'str', 'owner':'str','failed':'int', 'granted_pe':'str', 'slots':'int'}))
print(df)
```

Using groupby I create three columns calculated on the "slots" column:

```
df_calculated = pd.concat([
    df.loc[:,['group', 'slots']].groupby(['group']).sum(),
    df.loc[:,['group', 'slots']].groupby(['group']).mean(),
    df.loc[:,['group', 'slots']].groupby(['group']).max()
    ], axis=1)
print(df_calculated)
```

```
       slots  slots  slots
group                     
g1         1    1.0      1
g50        9    4.5      8
```

**Issue 1**: Naming the new columns appropriately
Can I add an argument to concat to name these columns "slots_sum", "slots_avg", and "slots_max"?

**Issue 2**: Add columns to df
I would prefer to **add** the new columns to the df just to the right of the "source" column ("slots" in this case). Desired output would look something like this:

```
  group owner  failed granted_pe  slots  slots_sum  slots_avg  slots_max
0    g1    u1       0     single      1          1        1.0          1
1   g50   u92       0     shared      8          9        4.5          8
2   g50   u92       0     shared      1
```

My actual df is 4.5 mil rows, 23 cols. I will want to do something similar for other columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `agg` with `add_prefix` then `merge` it back

```
yourdf=df.merge(df.groupby('group')['slots'].agg(['sum','mean','max']).add_prefix('slots_').reset_index(),how='left')
Out[86]: 
  group owner  failed    ...     slots_sum  slots_mean  slots_max
0    g1    u1       0    ...             1         1.0          1
1   g50   u92       0    ...             9         4.5          8
2   g50   u92       0    ...             9         4.5          8
```

Comment: This produces the output I am looking for. Thanks! Any idea how merge performs vs concat on millions of rows?

Comment: @KarlBaker if that is the case ,I recommend, using transform and add your new column one by one

Comment: How would I implement transform?

Comment: @KarlBaker like `df['slots_sum']=df.groupby('group')['slots'].transform('sum')` and do it one by one, save the time with `merge .`

Comment: I'm running into a problem with `transform`. I've converted my data to categorical because that saves ~80% space in memory. When I run `transform('sum')` I get "TypeError: Categorical cannot perform the operation sum". Is there a workaround for this? I tried `transform(np.sum)` but same error.

Comment: @KarlBaker you may need to convert it back . category is consider as object , which is not for sum

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `keys` parameter in pd.concat then merge multiindex column headers

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['g1', 'u1', 0, 'single', 1],
                   ['g50', 'u92', '0', 'shared', '8'],
                   ['g50', 'u92', '0', 'shared', '1']], 
                  columns=['group', 'owner', 'failed','granted_pe', 'slots'])
df = (df.astype(dtype={'group':'str', 'owner':'str','failed':'int', 'granted_pe':'str', 'slots':'int'}))

df_calculated = pd.concat([
    df.loc[:,['group', 'slots']].groupby(['group']).sum(),
    df.loc[:,['group', 'slots']].groupby(['group']).mean(),
    df.loc[:,['group', 'slots']].groupby(['group']).max()
    ], axis=1, keys=['sum','mean','max'])
df_calculated.columns = [f'{j}_{i}' for i,j in df_calculated.columns]
print(df_calculated)
```

Output:

```
       slots_sum  slots_mean  slots_max
group                                  
g1             1         1.0          1
g50            9         4.5          8
```